# how to deal with a path containing space in iis express

Tags: windows-7, iis-express

My problem is:
When starting IIS express 8.0 by command line, I use

```
iisexpress /config:C:\"Program Files"\"IIS Express"\AppServer\applicationhost.config
```

However, "Program Files" and "IIS Express" contains space. I got error even I use quotes:

```
Command-line switches must be preceded by '-' or '/'.Run 'iisexpress.exe /?' for more information
```

What can I do? OS: Windows 7

Comment: Try `iisexpress /config:"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\AppServer\applicationhost.config"` or `iisexpress "/config:C:\Program Files\IIS Express\AppServer\applicationhost.config"`

Comment: yes, both are OK. Thanks!